# .splice not removing element correctly

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using ngFor let `let i = index;` then I'm passing the i into the splice, which removes all json elements, but one. The watchingGroup part of the code is splicing fine. It's just the this.posts that isn't working right.

`<div class="row" *ngFor="let post of posts;let i = index;">`

When you click the button to execute function, this runs

`this.posts = this.posts.splice(i, 1);`

Why isn't it removing the specified element from `i`?

```
 removeFromWatchList(id: string, watchingGroup: string[], i) {


    var index = watchingGroup.indexOf(this.userId); // <-- Not supported in <IE9

    if (index !== -1) {
      watchingGroup.splice(index, 1);
    }
    console.log(watchingGroup);
    var unique = watchingGroup.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
      return index === self.indexOf(elem);
    });
    this.uniqueResult = unique;


    this.watchListService

      .addToWatchList(auctionId, this.uniqueResult)
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          this.counter++;
          console.log("COUTNER: " + this.counter);

          console.log("SUCCESS");
        },
        err => {
          // Handle error response
          console.log("ERROR");
        }
      );

      this.posts = this.posts.splice(i, 1);


  }
```

```
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let post of posts;let i = index;">
      <div class="col-md-9 col-centered">

        <div class="listingCard" [@simpleFadeAnimation]="'in'" >

          <div class=container>
            <div class="row"> </div>

            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-md-5">

                <button id="watchListButton" type="button" mat-raised-button (click)="removeFromWatchList(post.id, post.watchingGroup, i)"
                  [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': (this.watchListItems ? 'green' : 'white'),'background-color': (!this.watchListItems ? 'white' : 'white') }">{{watchButtonValue}}</button>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: show the relevant template where the function is called and the entire function

Comment: Which element is removed now by the code and you don't have to reassigned the variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**`splice`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) mutates the original array and returns the deleted item from the array as can be seen from the syntax at MDN:

> ```
> var arrDeletedItems = array.splice(start[, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]]])
> ```

So you should be seeing changes in the `posts` directly. Don't `reassign` like this:

```
this.posts = this.posts.splice(i, 1);
```

Just doing this should work:

```
this.posts.splice(i, 1);
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the explanation. It's working perfectly now

Comment: I tried to when I posted comment, but it told me to wait 6 mins. Got it now for you